# Wordpress Gallery showing all images uploaded to page instead of only the selected ones when creating the gallery

Tags: wordpress, image, gallery, lightbox, shortcode

Lets say I have a page with two gallerys

[gallery ids="111,222,333,444"]

and

[gallery ids="555,666,777"]

now when i click on one of these galleries, the lightbox is showing me all images (1-7). To be specific, it's showing all images uploaded to the page.

Where is the point in selecting images to show up in the gallery when all images uploaded to the page will show up. Is there any simple way to only show the images selected for the gallery? Seems like nobody has provided an answer on stackoverflow yet...

Using wordpress 4.0

Thanks!!

Comment: Lightboxing is not a native function of the gallery. What plugin are you using? Most likely it is the plugin logic causing this.